# Losing protected ranges when downloading excel from sheets and sheets to excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have been using excel documents containing protected ranges and hidden sheets, it seems like this can be circum navigated by importing into google sheets and likewise when doing the same in google sheets the functionality is lost when downloading as excel.

I understand the principles behind why this happens but I am curious as to whether there is any way of keeping this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible since both are different technologies. Microsoft's protection works with the file itself while Google's protection checks the permissions from each Google account.

Not long ago Google added a [compatibility mode](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9406611) for office files so you don't have to convert the files to Google Docs to open them, however this view still has limited features and it is not possible to work with the same type of protection in both platforms.

Reference:

- [Work with Microsoft Office files](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308757)
- [Edit Office files](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055139)

Comment: Thanks Fernando I did fear that this would be the answer.